# JMenuItem displays weird name

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

I got my inv finally working! :D But, you know... now... it's dumb. I want it to say "Use Item 1" or whatever when I Right-click so I do this:

```
        if (actItemx == "Item 1") {
            popup.add(dropMenuItem + " " + actItemx); // should print "Use Item 1"
            popup.add(cancelMenuItem);
        }
```

Looks fine to me... but... when I compile, it's fine. When I run it, it's fine... but when I DO IT:
[image: waaaaht]

I would have sworn that because it's displayed correctly in CMD that it would display correctly on JMenu... weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
popup.add(dropMenuItem + " " + actItemx);
```

That command is adding the toString() representaion of the dropMenuItem Swing component, plus a space, the the String value of actItemx.

I would guess you want:

```
popup.add(dropMenuItem.getText() + " " + actItemx);
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  Also, use `equals()` for string comparison, not `==`.  But wouldn't the better solution be `dropMenuItem.setText()` and add it instead of a `String`?

Comment: I can't really figure out what the OP is trying to do. I was assuming there was some kind of parent menu item and he is trying to create a child item based on the text of the parent, so he doesn't want to overwrite the existing menu item, but instead create a new one. I was mainly trying to describe the cause of the problem and let the poster decide the proper solution.